# Docker, symfony: jшибка при попытке подключения к mysql контейнеру через php

Tags: php, mysql, docker, symfony

Проблема в подключении к контейнеру mysql через php-cli - в сам контейнер с базой зайти могу и phpstorm к нему коннектится, а вот когда запускаю консольные команды проекта, вылетает ошибка базы.

Причем, ситуация следующая: пишу в docker-compose переменные окружения для php-cli и, когда ставлю hostname=localhost (как было бы без докера), то возникает ошибка "No such file or directory", а когда hostname=mysql (по имени контейнера - как рекомендует весь интернет) - ошибка "Connection refused".

Что еще интересно, phpstorm подключается по хосту localhost, а по mysql - тот же "Connection refused".

Проект на симфони, все стандартно, структура такая: в корне проекта docker-compose.yml, каталог app: в нем приложение, .env и т. д., в корне же каталог docker со всеми докер-файлами.

Docker-compose:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db_name
      MYSQL_USER: app
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: app
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
    volumes:
      - ./docker/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "33060:3306"

  php-fpm:
    build:
      context: docker/php-fpm
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: mysql://app:app@mysql:33060/db_name?serverVersion=5.7
      APP_ENV: dev

  php-cli:
    build:
      context: docker/php-cli
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: mysql://app:app@mysql:33060/db_name?serverVersion=5.7
      APP_ENV: dev

  nginx:
    build:
      context: docker/nginx
    depends_on:
      - php-fpm
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Внутри `docker-compose` вам нужно подсоединяться по внутреннему порту БД - 3306. Порт 33060 - это для внешних соединений. Сервисы внутри контейнеров общаются напрямую внутри `docker-compose`, а не через внешние порты.

[Источник](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)
[Перевод на русском](https://dker.ru/docs/docker-compose/networking-in-compose/)

> Each container can now look up the hostname web or db and get back the appropriate container’s IP address. For example, web’s application code could connect to the URL postgres://db:5432 and start using the Postgres database.

> It is important to note the distinction between HOST_PORT and CONTAINER_PORT. In the above example, for db, the HOST_PORT is 8001 and the container port is 5432 (postgres default). Networked service-to-service communication uses the CONTAINER_PORT. When HOST_PORT is defined, the service is accessible outside the swarm as well.

> Within the web container, your connection string to db would look like postgres://db:5432, and from the host machine, the connection string would look like postgres://{DOCKER_IP}:8001.

Comment: Благодарю, причина действительно была в этом! Я не сообразил, что это коннект внутри сети докера.